# Sequelize findAll query with transaction and using limiit and offset its not working

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to add pagination using transaction on sequelize but when i add both limit and offset its showing an error as  SequelizeDatabaseError: Invalid column name 'typeId'.

```
try {
    await sequelize.transaction(async (transaction) => {
        data = await Test.findAll({
          order: [['id', 'DESC']],
          where: { type: 'Y' },
          attributes: ['id', 'type', 'name'],
          include: [
            {
                model: xyz,
                as: 'xyz',
                attributes: ['id'],
                include: {
                    model: efg,
                    as: 'efg',
                    attributes: ['id', 'typeId'],
                },
            },
            {
                model: abc,
                as: 'abc',
                attributes: ['id'],
                include: {
                    model: ijk,
                    as: 'ijk',
                    attributes: ['id', 'name'],
                },
            }
          ],
          transaction,
          limit: 10,
          offset: 0,
        }).then(res=>{
          return res;
        })
      });
} catch(e) {

}
```

Any advice would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: typeId field is present inside efg  table

Comment: Do you see `start transaction` with some uuid. If so transaction is working fine. Check your column if it's there. Or more specifically check your model if you have defined the column ther.

Answer (score 1):

You need to the transaction as a second argument as follows -

```
try {
    await sequelize.transaction(async (transaction) => {
        data = await Test.findAll({
          order: [['id', 'DESC']],
          where: { type: 'Y' },
          attributes: ['id', 'type', 'name'],
          include: [
            {
                model: xyz,
                as: 'xyz',
                attributes: ['id'],
                include: {
                    model: efg,
                    as: 'efg',
                    attributes: ['id', 'typeId'],
                },
            },
            {
                model: abc,
                as: 'abc',
                attributes: ['id'],
                include: {
                    model: ijk,
                    as: 'ijk',
                    attributes: ['id', 'name'],
                },
            }
          ],
          // comment the line below
          // transaction,
          limit: 10,
          offset: 0,
        },
        { transaction }
        ).then(res=>{
          return res;
        })
      });
} catch(e) {

}
```

I know that [Official documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html) describes executing transaction for `findAll` method the way you have implemented but that didn't work as expected in my case when I tried.

Comment: I tried with above code passed transaction as a second argument but still not working showing same error Invalid column typeId

Comment: I think, your problem has nothing to do with the transaction, I suggest you to temporarily remove `typeId` from `sequelize` statement and check if that executes successfully.

Comment: Yeah i tried in that way also but then it's showing another error as SequelizeDatabaseError: A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be unique.

Comment: I think you have not framed question in a right way. I request you to post models which are used in sequelize statement and an error that you are getting on the console. I also suggest you to form a sequelize statement first and then think about converting it to transaction.

Comment: @Sujeet Agrahari can you please share me your code I will check once whether it works or not